# Python - Initialize a list of named tuples and pass it to a function

Tags: python

I asked my first question yesterday, and hope that I've learned how to better present my issue today. The code below is a simple example that contains the issues of interest to me. It has a couple of flaws that I want to ask about.

```
from collections import namedtuple

Name = 'Square'
Point = namedtuple('Point', 'x y')

PointBegin = (0, 0)
PointList = (
                 (1, 0)
                 (1, 1)
                 (0, 1)
                 (0, 0)
             )

def move_to(pt)
    print('Begin at (', pt.x, ',', pt.y, ')')

def draw_to(pt)
    print('Draw to (', pt.x, ',', pt.y, ')')

def draw(name, bgn_pt *pt_list) :
    print 'Drawing object ', name
    move_to(bgn_pt)
    for pt in pt_list:
        draw_to(pt.x, pt.y)

#Call the draw function, passing the list of named tuples.
draw(Name, PointBegin, *PointList)
```

First, PointList is not correctly initialized as there's no way for it to know that each sub-list is a Point. Is there any way to initialize this with minimal verbosity? I need to generate this from external data.

Second, the syntax for passing PointList to the draw function is incorrect. Can anyone suggest the correct syntax?

In my question yesterday, I suggested a class, rather than a named tuple. What type of value is best for this?

I'm not too concerned about any other syntax or convention errors. I can figure them out. BTW, I'm using Iron Python with real-time function extensions. But I don't expect that to be relevant to my questions.

Comment: You’re missing a lot of commas. Also `PointList = [Point(1, 0), ...]` would be a list of points; at the moment, you seem to be trying to create a tuple.

Comment: Your `PointList` isn't a list type (it's not even valid code right now without some commas), and the signature of `draw` is missing a comma. You would also just pass the list rather than consider it a `*` argument, so you probably want it to look like `def draw(name, bgn_pt, pt_list)`.

Comment: *"I'm not too concerned about any other syntax or convention errors"* Then how can you expect anyone else to be concerned with helping you if you can't be bothered to get basic syntax correct?

Comment: *"I suggested a class, rather than a named tuple. What type of value is best for this?"* For that, use a class if you want to be able to change the values of the attributes. Use a `namedtuple` if you want the attributes to be immutable.

Comment: Yes, my example was missing some commas, and some colons too.

Comment: You provided the key element that i overlooked. To write "Point(0,0)" rather than simply "(0,0)". After that, the second issue of removing the splat from the pt_list function argument was obvious. As far as the syntax errors: I didn't mean they're unimportant, or that I don't care about them. Only that they are easily identified and solved. After reading your answer, it took me only a few minutes to get the whole example to run by pasting it into the interpreter window. Thanks for your help. I now need to respond to the very thorough answer below from @Bruno.

Answer (score 2):

Ok let's go for a quick rundown...

```
from collections import namedtuple

Name = 'Square'
```

Convention in Python is to use `all_lower_with_underscores` for variable and function names and keep `SnakeCase` names for classes. So this should be

```
name = "Square"
```

...

```
Point = namedtuple('Point', 'x y')

PointBegin = (0, 0)
```

Two points here (lame pun, sorry):

First the naming, cf above (should be something like `point_begin` - actually `start_point` or `orgin` would be more correct but anyway).

Then, if you want this to be a `Point`, you have to make it a point instead of a `tuple`:

```
start_point = Point(0, 0)

PointList = (
                 (1, 0)
                 (1, 1)
                 (0, 1)
                 (0, 0)
             )
```

Naming again, plus 1/ this is not a `list`, 2/ it's not valid Python syntax, and 3/ if you want a list of `Point` you have to ask for it explicitely. Oh and yes: a collection is usually denoted by a plural form, ie "points".

I think that in this case you want something like:

```
 coords = [(1, 0),  (1, 1), (0, 1), (0, 0)]
 points = [Point(x, y) for x, y in coords]


def move_to(pt)
```

Syntax : you need the ":" here:

```
def move_to(pt):
```

Also readability is a very important part of Python's philosophy. If you meant "point", by all means spell it "point":

```
def move_to(point): 
    print('Begin at (', point.x, ',', point.y, ')')
```

Have mercy and use string formatting

```
    print("Begin at ({}, {})".format(point.x, point.y))


def draw_to(pt)
    print('Draw to (', pt.x, ',', pt.y, ')')
```

Idem

```
def draw(name, bgn_pt *pt_list) :
```

Idem plus s/bgn_pt/start_point/g (or origin or whatever makes sense but by all means something that requires no effort to be understood), and you need a comma between parameters ie  `def draw(name, start_point, *points)`

Also, the `*args` syntax is for varargs. Here your function expects a list (or any iterable) of `Point` so there's no use in using this syntax:

```
def draw(name, start_point, points):
    print 'Drawing object ', name
```

string formatting at the rescue:

```
   print("Drawing object {}".format(name))
```

...

```
    move_to(bgn_pt)
    for pt in pt_list:
        draw_to(pt.x, pt.y)
```

cf above (naming etc). Also your `draw_to` function expects a single `Point`, not two `x` and `y` argument

```
    move_to(start_point)
    for point in points:
        draw_to(point)


#Call the draw function, passing the list of named tuples.
```

Well this time we indeed pass a list of Points ;)

```
draw(name, start_point, points)
```

Now for the whole corrected code:

```
from collections import namedtuple

# define data types and functions first   
Point = namedtuple('Point', 'x y')

def move_to(point)
    print('Begin at ({}, {})'.format(point.x, point.y))

def draw_to(point)
    print('Draw to ({}, {})'.format(point.x, point.y))

def draw(name, start_point *points):
    print('Drawing object {}'.format(name))
    move_to(start_point)
    for point in points:
        draw_to(point)

# now our variables. 
# NB we wrap this in a `if __name__ == "__main__"`
# to gard this part from being executed if this script
# is imported as a module

if __name__ === "__main__":    
    start_point = Point(0, 0)
    coords = [(1, 0),  (1, 1), (0, 1), (0, 0)]
    points = [Point(x, y) for x, y in coords]
    name = "square"
    draw(name, start_point, points)
```

Comment: Thanks much for your very extensive answer. I feel bad now that didn't comment earlier on the first answer from @eyllanesc. I had the code running, but went to lunch. When I came back, I found your answer. I'm concerned that you have taken my example too seriously. My actual task has nothing to do with points or drawing or print statements. My key need was to get the syntax correct for creating a list of named tuples and passing the list as an argument. I made up this example based on my experience with the first question I posed yesterday.

Comment: Since you made such a complete effort to help, I'll share that I'm actually testing vehicle control software, running on hardware-in-the-loop, driving a simulation of the vehicle that  provides feedback. I need to stimulate each detectable fault condition and verify the measured response. I need a Test() function with arguments to identify the fault and the hardware pin and a list of other values. Things like voltage to apply, delay before fault declared, fault ID, severity level, etc. The Test() function compares response to expectations. Several voltages. Several results. Many fault sources.

Comment: @NorseMN don't feel concerned - the answer is not only for your own use but for anyone reading this post, and that's why I took the few minutes to post a "corrected" version that is not only technically correct but also pythonic.